# TexteEditingController is always empty

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to implement the email/password auth from Firebase but the emailController and passwordController send nothing tue my SubmitButton (or my TestButton)

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => LoginScreenState();
}

class LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            LoginEmail(emailController: emailController),
            const SizedBox(height: 30.0),
            LoginPassword(passwordController: passwordController),
            const SizedBox(height: 30.0),
            SubmitButton(
              email: emailController.text.trim(),
              password: passwordController.text.trim(),
            ),
            TestButton(
              textTest: emailController.text.trim(),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: LoginButton(
                text: 'Se connecter avec Google',
                icon: FontAwesomeIcons.google,
                color: Colors.blue,
                loginMethod: AuthService().googleLogin,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**LoginEmail**

```
class LoginEmail extends StatelessWidget {
  LoginEmail({
    Key? key,
    required this.emailController,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController emailController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
      child: TextField(
        controller: emailController,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Email'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**LoginPassword**

```
class LoginPassword extends StatelessWidget {
  LoginPassword({
    Key? key,
    required this.passwordController,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController passwordController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
      child: TextField(
        controller: passwordController,
        obscureText: true,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Password',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**SubmitButton** - $email and $password print nothing

```
class SubmitButton extends StatelessWidget {
  SubmitButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.email,
    required this.password,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final email;
  final password;
  final AuthService authService = AuthService();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        try {
          print('onPress email = $email et password = $password');
          await authService.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: 'myEmail',
            password: 'myPw',
          );
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
        } catch (e) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text(e.toString()),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
      child: const Text('Se connecter'),
    );
  }
}
```

**TestButton** - $textTest print nothing

```
class TestButton extends StatelessWidget {
  TestButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.textTest,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final textTest;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        try {
          print('onPress email = $textTest');
        } catch (e) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text(e.toString()),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
      child: const Text('Test'),
    );
  }
}
```

I was expecting to pass the value of emailController.text and passwordControlle.text to the SubmitButton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the widget build, it is getting string from controller. The initial text is empty for `TextEditingController`, and it is getting empty text on `TestButton`.  You can pass controller instance itself, which will be passed by reference.

It will be like

```dart
class TestButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.textTest,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController textTest;
```

And pass TextEditingController

```dart
 TestButton( textTest: emailController,),
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more [TextEditingController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html)